# $trc(A)=0$.why $A=M+N$ where $M$ and $N$ are nilpotent matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $trc(A)=0$.why $A=M+N$ where $M$ and $N$ are nilpotent matrices?($A \in {M_n}$)

Comment: Welcome to math.se! What have you tried so far?